# How to determine that if $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+2}}>\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^3+2}}$ for any n is natural number

Tags: inequality

How to prove that $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+2}}>\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^3+2}}$ for any n is natural number

I have that problem when tried to determine an alternating series conditional converge or not. It can be proved absolute convergent easily by limit comparison test but prove that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ is a problem to me.

Comment: Why not use the decreasing property of the function $x/\sqrt{x^3+2}$?

Comment: Can you explain further, I don't know much about what you call decreasing property.

Comment: I mean $f(x)=x/\sqrt{x^3+2}$ is a decreasing function. You can test this by derivative.

Comment: @aukxn I prove that the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}$ is strictly decreasing when $x>2^{2/3}$ in my answer, which implies your inequality for $n\ge 2>2^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^3+2}-\frac{3x^3}{2\sqrt{x^3+2}}}{x^3+2}<0\!\iff\! \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}<\frac{3x^3}{2(x^3+2)\sqrt{x^3+2}}$.

$\!\iff\!2(x^3+2)<3x^3\!\iff\! 4<x^3\!\iff\! x>\sqrt[3]{4}=2^{2/3}$.

Since $n\ge 2>2^{2/3}$, we have $f(n)<f(n+1)$. Your inequality is false for $n\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Why not using $f(x)=x^2/(x^3+2)$? The computations would be easier.

Comment: Why? A nonnegative function $f$ is decreasing if and only if $g(x)=f(x)^2$ is decreasing. In this application, we can assume $x\ge0$, so $x/\sqrt{x^3+2}\ge0$.

Comment: You *don't* need to look at $x<0$ for applying the function to the problem.

Comment: We've learned more about the function in the full real domain by calculating this instead, but it's a good point since it's irrelevant in this problem, although it could be helpful if OP needed to extend the domain for some purpose.

Answer (score 2):

$$n\sqrt{(n+1)^3+2}>(n+1)\sqrt{n^3+2}$$$$\!\iff\!n^2((n+1)^3+2)>(n^2+2n+1)(n^3+2)$$

$$\!\iff\! n^2(n^3+2)+n^2(3n^2+3n+1)>n^2(n^3+2)+(2n+1)(n^3+2)$$

$$\!\iff\! 3n^4+3n^3+n^2>2n^4+n^3+4n+2$$

$$\!\iff\! n^4+2n^3+n^2>4n+2,$$

which follows from $n^4+n^3+n^3+n^2\stackrel{\text{AM-GM}}\ge 4n^3=4n+4n(n^2-1)>4n+2$ for $n\ge 2$. Your inequality is false for $n\in\{0,1\}$.

Or notice: $n^4+2n^3+n^2=(n+1)^2n^2>(n+1)^2n>5n\ge 4n+2$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: How can you know that $n^4 \ge 4n^3$ and $4n^3 \gt 4n+2$ and what is the $\ge$ with AM-GM on its. This is the 1st time I see it

Comment: @aukxn AM-GM (Arithmetic-Geometric Mean inequality) says $\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}\ge \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$ when $a_i>0$. In this case, $n^4+n^3+n^3+n^2\ge 4\sqrt[4]{n^4n^3n^3n^2}=4n^3$ for $n\ge 0$.

Comment: @aukxn $4n^3=4n+4n(n^2-1)>4n+2$ is true simply because $4n(n^2-1)>2$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: @aukxn I've added an argument that doesn't use AM-GM.